# How do I search an online document for specific string and it's value?

Tags: string, vb.net

Example, Online document: [removed link as no longer needed]

Which outputs:

```
Value1=1
Value2=5

The rest of this document would have random text to ignore.
```

I would like to search for `Value1` and `Value2`, then output it's value [I need this to be expandable if I decide to add new information in the future]

[the output may be longer than one character, and might be text rather than a number]

```
Dim Value1Result as Integer = [value from online file] '1 in this case
Dim Value2Result as Integer = [value from online file] '5 in this case
```

Comment: What's your question specifically?  How to download it to a string (without saving to a file), or how to search the string for the value?

Comment: So, what are the rules?  Is it case sensitive?  Is it always a value name followed by an equals sign followed by a value?  Is the value always numeric?  Is each value always on its own line?  etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Well, if you can choose the format, then by all means, I would choose some standard data format which supports multiple values, like JSON or XML, or even CSV for that matter.  Anything standard and well defined would be better.

Comment: If you aren't going to use a standard format, then there are several ways of parsing it.  The simplest would be to use a `StringReader` to read one line at a time, then use `String.Split` to split on the `=` and then use `Integer.TryParse` to parse the value on the right side of the `=`.  Personally I'd choose to use regex instead, since it's easier and more powerful, but it does involve more of a learning curve, so, depending on your familiarity with it, you may not want to go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Added logic to strip the version number.  Very basic but as long as the format doesn't change it should work.  You'll need to handle parsing to int, double, etc if you ever use "1.2" or whatever for a version.

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to download the file, store it in a local variable, and then do something with it.  Comment if this is not the case and I will adjust.

I would do this by creating a WebClient, downloading the data, converting it to a string, and then operating on it.  I did not add any headers - dropbox doesn't require it, but something to keep in mind for production...  Small example below:

```
Dim bResult() As Byte
Dim sUrl As String = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bus2q71wsn9txuz/Test.txt?dl=0"
Using client As New WebClient
    bResult = client.DownloadData(sUrl)
End Using
Dim retData As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bResult)
Dim retList As List(Of String) = retData.Split(Environment.NewLine).ToList()
Dim sMin = retList(0).Split("=").Last()
Dim sNew = retList(1).Split("=").Last()
```

Comment: Ok, I feel like you should be able to do that, but I edited it.  Please note that this will only work as long as your format doesn't change, and the version number stays after the "="